# Nodejs get request reading body data

Tags: node.js, get, request

this is an example response im getting from request

````
ill show you what an actual request looks like ```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-INFO:NODE="video-edge-c2b07c.dfw02",B="false",MANIFEST-NODE-TYPE="weaver_cluster",MANIFEST-NODE="video-weaver.dfw02",SUPPRESS="true",SERVER-TIME="1571716283.0",TRANSCODESTACK="2017TranscodeQS_V2",USER-IP="38.131.137.53",SERVING-ID="614d6b4085434f49beeb41fb36326bf6",CLUSTER="dfw02",ABS="false",VIDEO-SESSION-ID="8194286829451308751",BROADCAST-ID="36033077616",STREAM-TIME="38185.0027399",FUTURE="true",USER-COUNTRY="US",MANIFEST-CLUSTER="dfw02"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="chunked",NAME="720p (source)",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=3625644,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2",VIDEO="chunked",FRAME-RATE=30.000
https://url.com.m3u8
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="720p30",NAME="720p",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2378938,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.4D401F,mp4a.40.2",VIDEO="720p30",FRAME-RATE=30.000
https://url.com.m3u8
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="480p30",NAME="480p",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1433938,RESOLUTION=852x480,CODECS="avc1.4D401F,mp4a.40.2",VIDEO="480p30",FRAME-RATE=30.000
https://url.com.m3u8
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="360p30",NAME="360p",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=630000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.4D401F,mp4a.40.2",VIDEO="360p30",FRAME-RATE=30.000
https://url.com.m3u8
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=VIDEO,GROUP-ID="160p30",NAME="160p",AUTOSELECT=YES,DEFAULT=YES
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=230000,RESOLUTION=284x160,CODECS="avc1.4D401F,mp4a.40.2",VIDEO="160p30",FRAME-RATE=30.000
https://url.com.m3u8
````

how would i go about extracting the url at the bottom this is just an example in an actual request body that gets returned it contains multiple urls.

Comment: Which format is it??

Comment: are you asking what format is body being returned in?

Comment: yes whether its a JSON??

Comment: no its not json thats the problem

Comment: Then what format is it??IF its plain text then you have to do string manipulation to get that

Comment: i updated the question to show exactly what body looks like. i assume thats plain text. also idk if it helps any but i usually always want the bottom url

Answer (score 0):

you can search by regex and find the matched format for that:

```js
const urlRegex =/https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/ig

// responseBodyText from the response you get
const matchedUrls = responseBodyText.match(urlRegex);

const extractedUrls = matchedUrls ? matchedUrls : []
// it should prints the all the urls on the response if there is any or empty array if not
```

example with your sample:
[image]

Comment: so one issue how can i fix these errors some times it comes back as
                url: matchedUrls[1]
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

or this

cannot read type match of undefined
let matchedUrls = body.match(urlRegex);

Comment: you can check for the `matchedUrls` if it's value `null` that means there are no urls on the response (just if statement) , check the answer updates Pls

Comment: ok that fixes null but what about this

this is what i get now

                    let matchedUrls = body.match(urlRegex);
                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined

Comment: Ya! the body now needs to be check , so the `.match` exists on the String Prototype object , just check it the body is a string and processed the flow

Comment: you should have a validation layer before the body reaches this stage!